# How can I remove spacing before the first item on a string?

Tags: python-3.x

Example:

```
time = "14:06"
Time = "2:06 PM"

print("The time you entered,",time,", is",Time,"in the 12-hour format.")
```

This prints: The time you entered, **14:06 ,** is 2:06 PM in the 12-hour format.

I want the space after 14:06 to be gone so that it'd look like this:

The time you entered, **14:06,** is 2:06 PM in the 12-hour format.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("The time you entered, {}, is {} in the 12-hour format.".format(time, Time))
```

https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/string.html#formatspec

PS: `time` is a module of the standard library. I suggest you to use `time24` and `time12` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add `sep=''` to the `print` statement. This is a custom separator (in Python3) between all items in the `print` statement. Then you will need to add the correct spacing manually.

```
time = "14:06"
Time = "2:06 PM"

# Original print statement
print("The time you entered,",time,", is",Time,"in the 12-hour format.", sep='')

# Updated print statement
print("The time you entered, ",time,", is ",Time," in the 12-hour format.", sep='')
```

**Outputs:**

```
# Original
The time you entered,14:06, is2:06 PMin the 12-hour format.

# Updated
The time you entered, 14:06, is 2:06 PM in the 12-hour format.
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print